# How to use 'auto' for declaring a pointer to an overloaded member function?

Tags: c++, auto, pointer-to-member

If I have an overloaded non-static member function, how can I use `auto` to declare a pointer for one version of that function?

```
struct Foo{
   void bar(){}
   void bar(int){}
};

auto ptr = &Foo::bar; // error: unable to deduce 'auto' from '&Foo::bar'
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't.

Well, you could do an explicit cast to the proper pointer type, but it's really no different from just putting the proper pointer type in place of `auto`:

```
using bar_ptr = void (Foo::*)();

bar_ptr ptr = &Foo::bar;

//or

auto ptr = (bar_ptr)&Foo::bar;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid explicitly mentioning the full type through such a set of functions:

```cpp
template <class... Params, class R>
    auto ovl(R(*f)(Params...)) {
    return f;
}

template <class... Params, class R, class T>
    auto ovl(R(T::*f)(Params...)) {
    return f;
}

template <class... Params, class R, class T>
    auto ovl_const(R(T::*f)(Params...) const) {
    return f;
}
```

Usage is as follows, providing the argument types of the targeted function:

```cpp
auto ptr = ovl<int>(&Foo::bar);
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zVIQ5NiImnKW0Vhb)

Overloads for varargs, `volatile`, ref-qualified, etc. member functions are left as an exercise for the reader.